# How To Interacting With Elements That Are Under Hidden Elements In Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to get data from a table element that is inside of a hidden div element.
I've tried a few things but nothing so far has worked for this case.

html:

```
<div class="hidden">
   <span class="spanTheMan">
      <table class="imATable">
         <tbody>...</tbody>
      </table>
   </span>
</div>
```

I found that you can include the hidden tag when searching for the element to find it, however the table itself doesn't have that tag

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='hidden']")
```

I found that you can use ".execute_script("arguments[0].;", element)"

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].<some sort of function>;", TableElement)
```

I believe this would work however, the function I need to use is a one that was written in python. To be clear it acknowledges there is a table element, just not the data inside it.

Answer (score 0):

In the xpath you should give the class associated to that tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='imATable']")
```

This should work because ultimately you are trying to access the table element.